# Unable to deploy react app with node backend on digital ocean app platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using react app with node backend. It runs perfect on local machine.

Now I am deploying it on digital ocean App Platform which directly pulls my code from github repository.

It gets successfully deployed there also but on going live App it gives error

"Cannot GET /"

my package.json of my client has

"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",